# How to avoid multiple selection in a listview in jquery mobile

Tags: html, listview, jquery-mobile

how to make the listview to allow selection of only one item.i used a list with < a href="#">, just to show what item is been selected. but i want,only one item in the list to be selected. It should not allow me to select another element. Can some help help me out with this

Comment: listview is not supposed to be used for selecting. put a working link to another page there and see what it does

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/SJ3GU/1/

Listview Docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/lists/index.html

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview"> 
            <li>Acura</li> 
            <li>Audi</li> 
            <li>BMW</li> 
            <li>Cadillac</li> 
            <li>Ferrari</li>
            <li><a href="#acura">Click for more info on the Acura</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="acura"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview"> 
            <li><a href="#home">Back Home</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i ve actually created the multiline list dynamically.When i click the element in a list , it goes to next page, but it should allow only one selection

Comment: I think you're looking for a radio button group, see the examples here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/forms/forms-radiobuttons.html